# Python: 2-D Kolmogorov-Smirnov with 2 samples

Tags: python, statistics, scipy

I have two datasets each in two dimensions : (X1,Y1) and (X2,Y2).
I want to be able to calculate a KS test statistic to determine whether values from these two datasets arise from the same or different distributions. I have used scipy.stats.ks_2samp before but that is to compare two datasets in one dimension or perhaps the probability distribution of the two samples. In this case however, I'm stuck with not probability distributions but discrete x and y values for both the samples. How can I go ahead and get the ks test value in python for this situation? I have separate numpy arrays for each of the parameters X1, Y1, X2 and Y2. 
Thank you!

Comment: I have to wonder what's the point of trying to carry out such a test. You can quite easily answer the question from first principles: from where did you get sample 1? and from where sample 2? If they had different origins, then they have different distributions. It doesn't matter if sample 1 comprises people on the north side of the railroad tracks and sample 2 the south side. Whether the two are practically different is an entirely different question, which KS or any other significance test cannot answer. If you are studying practical difference, you have to come up with a different approach.

Comment: Well essentially I simulate both datasets from a chi square frequentist approach. I generate one dataset from accepted uncertainty values added to a pre-existing model, and then the other group gets the rejected uncertainty ranges on the same pre-existing model. So I know that they are arising from different origins. I do however need a value like the ks test statistic to quantify this. Thoughts?

Comment: Those chi square acceptance/rejection values signify different outcomes for the problem I'm working with, therefore I am aiming to create distinct datasets via this approach. Bottom line, I'm creating what I think are two different sample datasets both 2-d. I just need a statistic to support that they are indeed different.

Comment: There is no multivariate (2-D) version of the KS test in scipy, nor have I seen it anywhere else. If you have binned values or discrete values with enough observation in each bin, then you can still use the chisquare test which is independent of the dimension but requires enough expected observations per bin or cell for the chisquare distribution to be a good approximation to the true distribution of the test statistic.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

<s>[This Notebook](http://nbviewer.ipython.org/url/cs.marlboro.edu/courses/spring2014/jims_tutorials/ahernandez/Apr_25.attachments/scic_stat_tests.ipynb#Two-Dimensional-K-S) provide a Python implementation for 2D K-S test with 2 samples. The `.py` file can be downloaded [here](http://cs.marlboro.edu/courses/spring2014/jims_tutorials/ahernandez/Apr_25.attachments). The code seems to be a translation of `C` code, the efficiency might be a problem if sample size is large.</s>
(broken link)

### More infomation

The algorithm is first developed in two papers

- [Peacock, J.A. 1983, Two-Dimensional Goodness-of-Fit Testing in Astronomy](http://adsabs.harvard.edu/abs/1983MNRAS.202..615P)
- [Fasano, G. and Franceschini, A. 1987, A Multidimensional Version of the Kolmogorov-Smirnov Test](http://adsabs.harvard.edu/abs/1987MNRAS.225..155F).

A nice introduction and the `C` implementation can be found in

- [Press, W.H. et al. 1992, Numerical Recipes in C](http://apps.nrbook.com/c/index.html), Section 14.7, p645.

  You can find `C++/Fortran` implementation in other versions of the book.

Here's a post titled [Beware the Kolmogorov-Smirnov test](https://asaip.psu.edu/Articles/beware-the-kolmogorov-smirnov-test) is also related to the subject, you may want to have a look.

### Update

I have also written a python implementation using numpy, it should have a better performance than the quoted notebook. You can find the code [here](https://github.com/syrte/ndtest).

You'd better check the codes (no matter which one used) with the original papers/books before any application. The python implementations of 2d KS test are far less examined than other covential tests in numpy/scipy.

Comment: Thank you, this is plenty helpful!

Comment: @AryaIyer I've also write one implementation, see the update above. However you should check the codes (no matter which one) with the papers/books. The python implementations of 2d KS test are far less checked than those in numpy/scipy.

Comment: the notebook link is broken